# How to straighten a 3D edge not along an axis?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm a new user but I've previous experience with Solidworks where I can put in specific angles and measurements to create the shapes I need. I'm trying to unlearn a lot of this so I can get good with Blender and one issue I am having is creating straight lines on 3D objects.
[image: Example]
[image: Example2]

For example in this image I would like the vertices to be as straight as possible but many of the solutions I find online give methods that involve snapping the vertices along the X, Y or Z axis which does not work for the angle I am working with.

Is there a way to select the very top and bottom vertex and then have every other other point between form a dead straight line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Select end faces.

[image]

- Change Transform Orientation to Normal.

[image]

- Press <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> to scale on Z axis. But because the Transform Orientation is set to normal, it will scale in the axis of the average of the face normals. Enter 0 as you scale to scale to 0, making it completely flat.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for answering, it's much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, but I'd recommend moonboots' solution. Custom transform orientations are more flexible.

Comment: @ Benus, I never think about Normals, it's simpler than custom no? In what way custom may be more flexible?

Comment: If you wanted to modify other parts of the mesh like the edges connected to the flat face for example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuzOS.gif . I only just learned about custom orientations from your post, and it might just be me, but i'll probably be using custom orientations more than scaling on normals now.

Comment: sure you're right, I was thinking about the current question  ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can select all these faces and in the *Transform Orientations* panel, click on the "+" in order to create a custom orientation, then flatten on the Z axis of this new orientation:

[image]

Also, you can activate the *Edge Flow* addon and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Set Linear* and it will straighten the faces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, very helpful!