How to align edges into a straight line?
Is there an easy way to flatten the selected edges (straighten them into one line) based on the average of the edges? They're not aligned to any axis.


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28063/straighten-edges-not-on-axis/28116#28116 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214036/how-to-flatten-a-vertex-path-a-list-of-connected-edges-into-a-straight-line-wh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249555/how-to-straighten-a-3d-edge-not-along-an-axis
